# Computing similarity matrix with mixed data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, similarities, mixed-type-data

I would like to compute similarity matrix (which I will further use for clustering purposes) from my data (failure data from automotive company). The data consist of these variables:

START DATE + TIME (dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss), DURATION (in seconds), DAY OF THE WEEK (mon,tue,...), WORKING TEAM (1,2,3), LOCALIZATION (1,2,3,...,20), FAILURE TYPE

From this, it is clear, that there are continuous and categorical data. What method would you suggest to calculate similarities between failure types? I think I can not use Euclidean distance, or Gowe's similarity.

Comment: I doubt there is any answer to this that is supported by statistics.

Comment: Why can't you use Gower distance/similarity?  It handles both continuous and categorical data.

Comment: @G5W Can you please point me to some example of manual compotation of Gower distance? I would like to implement it into my c# application but I can not find any library for it and I am not sure I understand how to compute it manually so I would be able to program it myself.

Comment: @MartinNemeth I do not have a lot to offer you there. The original paper is here [Gower (1971) A general coefficient of similarity and some of its properties. Biometrics 27 857-874.](http://venus.unive.it/romanaz/modstat_ba/gowdis.pdf)  and [This chapter](http://84.89.132.1/~michael/stanford/maeb5.pdf) has a worked-out example.